# Restructuring JSON to create a new JSON where properties are grouped according to similar values

Tags: javascript, array, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, iteration

I have a JSON structure in the following example format:

```
[
  {date: '01-01-2021', name: 'House 1', value: '500'},
  {date: '01-01-2021', name: 'House 2', value: '600'},
  {date: '01-01-2021', name: 'House 3', value: '700'},
  {date: '01-01-2021', name: 'House 4', value: '800'},
  {date: '01-02-2021', name: 'House 1', value: '200'},
  {date: '01-02-2021', name: 'House 2', value: '100'},
  {date: '01-02-2021', name: 'House 3', value: '300'},
  {date: '01-02-2021', name: 'House 4', value: '1000'},
]
```

I have written logic to group it in the following format:

```
[
  {date: '01-01-2021', 'House 1': 500, 'House 2': 600, 'House 3': 700, 'House 4': 800},
  {date: '01-02-2021', 'House 1': 200, 'House 2': 100, 'House 3': 300, 'House 4': 1000},
]
```

Below is code I have written. It works and seems to be efficient, but I am curious if this was the best approach or if there is a simpler way to accomplish this task? The actual data set contains a total of 2274 objects that is reduced to an array of 748 objects.

Code:

```
const housing_table_data = ((json_data) => {
        const unique_dates = housing_data.reduce((accumulator, current_value) => {
            if (accumulator.indexOf(current_value.date) === -1) {
                accumulator.push(current_value.date);
            }
            return accumulator;
        }, []);

        let table_data = [];

        unique_dates.forEach((date, index) => {
            table_data.push({date: date});

            let house_groupings = housing_data.filter(data => data.date=== date);

            house_groupings.forEach(group => {
                table_data[index][group.name] = group.value;
            });
        });

        return table_data;
    })(housing_data);
```

Comment: That isn't JSON. See [RFC 8259, Section 7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-7): strings use double quotes. And the only unquoted symbols in JSON are `true`, `false` and `null`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for sharing! I came from a background in PL/SQL, so single quotes are very much ingrained into my programming. One day I hope to break that habit!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Scoping issues

You are using an "immediately invoked function expression" (IIFE) here to scope the `unique_dates`, but in the process you forgot to use the function argument you introduced to correctly scope the function you have there.

Note how you have `((json_data) => {` but the body of the function you  define there never refers to `json_data`. That's not really that great.
This doesn't give you any benefit here so instead you should just unwrap that IIFE.

#### Naming Convention

I just want to mention that the majority of styleguides I have seen for javascript advocate the use of `camelCase` variable names over `snake_case` names. Seeing that you are consistent in your use of `snake_case` that's really just personal preference, though.

#### Algorithmic advice

You can cut the number of iterations over the json_data down to a single iteration instead of two iterations. It allows you to avoid filtering the `housing_data` in the `forEach`.

The "trick" to see is the idea of using the date as a key into an accumulator object instead of using an accumulator array. To transform the accumulator into your target structure you can then use `Object.values`:

```
const grouped_accumulated = housing_data.reduce((accumulator, current_value) => {
    if (!accumulator.hasOwnProperty(current_value.date)) {
        accumulator[current_value.date] = { date: current_value.date };
    }
    accumulator[current_value.date][current_value.name] = current_value.value;
    return accumulator;
}, {});
const housing_table_data = Object.values(grouped_accumulated);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! 

Great catch in pointing out my scoping issue. I think I was moving to quick when refactoring and forgot to change it!

Everyone at my company uses snake case even though I do prefer camel case. I figured it's easiest to just go with the flow.

Your solution is very elegant and improves performance tremendously. Thank you for showing me this and also teaching me something new! I did have to modify it ever-so slightly to return the accumulator and provide a default value. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

### Names!

JavaScript convention is to use `camelCase` for names rather than `snake_case`.

### Using a Hash Map

Using [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to locate unique entries has a complexity of \$O(n)\$ for each record in the source array, where \$n\$ is number of unique items. This can be reduced to \$O(1)\$ by using a hash map.

JavaScript has several ways to use hash maps (Object property names, [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), and [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet))

In this case you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to group by unique item values `Map(key, {date: key})` creates a hash for `key` and stores the object `{date: key}` with the hash

### Segregate names from data

This type of task may often require minor changes when data sources are outside your control. It pays to use a more generic solution that removes the hard coded property naming from the function.

To remove the hard coded properties `date`, `name`, `value` from the functions body we can divide the task into two,

1. Create a record for each unique named property
2. Add a new property (key/value pair) to an object based on the value of two properties in a source object.

#### Grouping by property

Using a `Map` create records for each unique named property value and add key value pairs as defined by the function above

```
const groupBy = (data, name, addKeyVal) => {
  const res = new Map();
  for (const record of data) {
    const val = record[name];           // unique Value 
    addKeyVal(                          // Add name and value to unique rec
      res.get(val) ?? res.set(val, {[name]: val}).get(val), // get unique rec, Create if needed
      record
    );
  }
  return [...res.values()];  // return as array of objects
}
```

<sub>For more on the operator [?? (Nullish coalescing operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) used.</sub>

#### Adding properties

A generic function that returns a function to extract and add the named key/value pair to a existing object

```
const keyValToRecord = (key, val) => (dest, src) => dest[src[key]] = src[val];
```

#### Names defined outside function

We can now extract the data with the property names being independent of the function's code

```
const valueByDate = groupBy(sourceData, "date", keyValToRecord("name", "value"));
```

Say your data source came with more data, eg each house had an insured value. Rather than rewrite/copy the whole function changing each named reference to `value`  to `insured` you need only change the call

```
const insuredByDate = groupBy(sourceData, "date", keyValToRecord("name", "insured"));
```

### Rewrite

Putting it all together we get

```js
const keyValToRecord = (key, val) => (dest, src) => dest[src[key]] = src[val];
const groupBy = (data, name, addKeyVal) => {
    const res = new Map();
    for (const record of data) {
        const val = record[name];                                  
        addKeyVal(res.get(val) ?? res.set(val, {[name]: val}).get(val), record);
    }
    return [...res.values()]; 
}

// Given source data 
const sourceData  = [{date: 1, name: "House1", value: 5}, {date: 1, name: "House2", value: 6}, {date: 1, name: "House3", value: 7}, {date: 1, name: "House4", value: 8}, {date: 2, name: "House1", value: 2}, {date: 2, name: "House2", value: 1}, {date: 2, name: "House3", value: 3}, {date: 2, name: "House4", value: 1}];

// Extract the data grouped by date
console.log(groupBy(sourceData, "date", keyValToRecord("name", "value")));
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what the other answers already said, I would offer

#### Use a `Set`

For getting a list of unique values, checking whether an item already is part of the result with a loop (and that's what `indexOf`/`includes` do) is not very efficient, leading to `O(n²)` time complexity. A `Set` uses a constant-time lookup instead, achieving overall `O(n)` complexity.

#### Use `map` instead of `forEach`

Your `table_data` is populated using a loop with a `push` in each iteration. And later, you look up the new item by its index to add a property for each `group`. Instead, use the `map` method and create the object at once. Or for mapping a `Set` to a array, you'd use `Array.from`.

---

Combining these would lead to

```
const housingTableData = (() => {
    const uniqueDates = new Set(housingData.map(value => value.date));

    return Array.from(uniqueDates, date => {
        const housing = {date};

        for (const group of housingData) {
            if (group.date === date) {
                housing[group.name] = group.value;
            }
        }
        return housing;
    });
})();
```

(Personally I prefer loop constructs over `filter`+`forEach` when it comes to executing side effects, like the creation of properties on the `housing` object).

---

And of course, as @Vogel612 advised, we can make this even more efficient by looping over the input just once. Since you tagged your question [es6](/questions/tagged/es6), I would however recommend to use a `Map` instead of an object for collecting the values by date:

```
const housingTableData = (() => {
    const groupsByDate = new Map();
    for (const {date, name, value} of housingData) {
        let group = groupsByDate.get(date);
        if (!group) {
            group = {date};
            groupsByDate.set(date, group);
        }
        group[name] = value;
    }
    return Array.from(groupsByDate.values());
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the suggestions in Vogel612's answer. Below are some suggestions about the current code.

#### prefer using `const`

> ```
> let table_data = [];
> ```

This variable `table_data` is never re-assigned so it can be declared using `const`. This helps avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

#### Use `Array.includes()`

If you still needed to check if an array includes an element:

> ```
> if (accumulator.indexOf(current_value.date) === -1) {
> ```

This can be simplified using [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
if (!accumulator.includes(current_value.date)) {
```